# outlook 2007: start showing full month view?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

How do I configure Outlook 2007 to show the calendar, preferably full month view, when it launches?

I'm using Win7 pro and am launching by typing "out" on the start menu, then hitting enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Outlook, choose the "Tools" menu, then click "Options...".
2. Click on the "Other" tab.
3. Under "General" (at the top of the dialog), click on "Advanced Options...".
4. Under "General Settings" (at the top of the dialog), next to "Startup in this folder:", click "Browse...".
5. Select "Calendar" form your desired (probably primary) mailbox, then click "OK".
6. Close out of all remaining open dialogs using "OK".

This will cause Outlook to startup in the calendar.

Outlook (at least 2007) remembers the last Calendar view you use - so open the calendar, then select your desired "Month" view.  As long as this is the last Calendar view you use, this is how it will appear again the next time you open Outlook.